# General term formula of sequence A255372 at OEIS

Tags: sequences-and-series

The [A255372](https://oeis.org/A255372) formula part shows that $ 
a_0 = a_1 = 0,\ a_2 = 1,\ a_n = 9*(10^{n-3} - a_{n-3} + \sum\limits_{i= 2}^{n-1}{a_i})\ for\ n\geqslant3$

But the following G.f truly confused me:$\frac{x^2*(x-1)^2}{(10*x-1)*(9*x^4-9*x^3+10*x-1)}$

I have tried $x=1$, $x=2$, $x=3$. It seems not match the sequence itself.

So, I tried to find the general term formula on my own.

Given $a_1 = 0$, $S_1 = S_2$, if we consider $S_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}$.

Thus, $a_n=9*(10^{n-3}-a_{n-3}+S_{n-1})$

But I do not know that to do next. I am stuck at this step.

Does anyone have some good ideas?

Comment: G.f. **does not** stand for "general formula". There is absolutely no point in plugging $x=1,2,3$, or any other value into it.

Comment: @IvanNeretin But what does it means? And is it possible to find a general formula for it?

Comment: It means "[generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)". As for the general formula, you have a fifth-order linear recurrence with ugly roots, so I wouldn't expect anything nice.

Comment: @IvanNeretin That is a sad story. But still thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"G.F." stands for **generating function**; that is to say, if $\{a_n\}_{n \ge 0}$ is a sequence, then its (ordinary) generating function is $$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n.$$  Evaluating $f(z)$ at various values of $z$ does not, then, furnish individual terms in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the generating function as given by $OEIS$ $$\text{gf}=\frac{x^2(x-1)^2 }{(10 x-1) \left(9 x^4-9 x^3+10 x-1\right)}$$ and develop is as a Taylor series at $x=0$. What you will get is $$x^2+18 x^3+261 x^4+3411 x^5+42057 x^6+499383 x^7+5775480 x^8+65506986
   x^9+O\left(x^{10}\right)$$ where the coefficients are the first terms of the sequence. Just continue to get the next.